# How to sort a list with two sorting rules?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list that I want to sort using to parameters. That means it are all values and if for example I have

```
A    2/2
B    3/3
C    3/4
```

I want the sorting C B A

I tried to implement that the following way:

```
methods.Sort((y, x) => x.GetChangingMethodsCount().CompareTo(y.GetChangingMethodsCount()));
            methods.Sort((y, x) => x.GetChangingClassesCount().CompareTo(y.GetChangingClassesCount()));
```

First sort the list with the second parameter and then sort it again with the first parameter. But the ordering isn0t correct. Any hints how to achieve that?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you're sorting it, then sorting it again. What you want to do is sort it by the first parameter, and if CompareTo returns 0 (they're the same), THEN resort by the second parameter. It's actually one call to Sort() with a longer function. Or use the extension methods given as answers, which are even better. :)

Comment: Yes I think i was stuck to some applications (e.g. Excel) where this kind of sorting works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is combine the two sort keys into a single function. If the first comparison returns 0, only then try the second one:

```
methods.Sort((y, x) => 
{
    int sort = x.GetChangingClassesCount().CompareTo(y.GetChangingClassesCount());
    if (sort == 0)
        sort = x.GetChangingMethodsCount().CompareTo(y.GetChangingMethodsCount());
    return sort;
});
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to use the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods like that :

```
methods.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetChangingMethodCount()).
        ThenByDescending(x => x.GetChangingClassesCount()).
        ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get not really the exact Result I'd like

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear (to me at least) if this is what you want based on your example, but you could give this a try:

```
var sortedMethods = methods.OrderByDescending(m => m.GetChangingMethodsCount()).ThenByDescending(m => m.GetChangingClassesCount());
```